# Hyper-V Management Tools not listed as an Addable Feature - Windows Server Essentials 2012

Tags: hyper-v, essentials-2012

I want to run Hyper-V manager on a virtual machine running Windows 2012 Server essentials.

I've seen videos of others using the Server Manager to add this feature to their Windows 2012 Servers, but when I follow their steps, I'm missing the selectable entry (that they are choosing) that would allow me to add this feature to my virtual server.

I only need the Hyper-V manager tools (not the service), but these aren't listed features for me to add. (Screenshot below)

[image]

How should I proceed?

Comment: Do you have an objection to installing a Windows 8 Workstation (or VM) and using it to manage Hyper-V?  The Windows 8 RSAT pack allows you to install the Hyper-V Manager, if WSE 2012 won't, and you don't need to burn money on a license for Server 2012 Standard.

Comment: Thanks for editing my post to include the screen shot. If it cost additional to use Hyper-V manager on 2012 Server Essentials, I will be looking for another alternative. I often manage this network remotely and need a machine with Hyper-V manager installed so I can backup another (more important) virtual machine (locally) from a remote location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is apparently by design.  [The Hyper-V Management Role is not available on Server 2012 Essentials](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/ba37d1a1-7969-4e3c-a1c3-386a9eaf703b/hyperv-management-role-not-available-on-essentials-2012).

The Hyper-V Management Role is available on Server 2012 Standard, or Windows 8, however.

Given that, my advice would be to either stand up a Server 2012 Standard box and install that role, or a Windows 8 workstation, if licensing costs are a factor.  The [Windows 8 RSAT download can be found here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28972), and the [Windows 8.1 RAST can be found here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39296).

Comment: These are the types of things that disappoint me from Microsoft. There is no technical reason why this application couldn't run on a server running 2012 Server Essentials, but (as you say) "by design" they make it practically impossible to install. These days, instead of providing standalone installers (where an application could run on any version of windows), they have restricted and predefined "feature menus". If it's not on the menu, you can't add it.

Comment: One more thing: At another company, I moved them from Hyper-V to Proxmox ( http://www.proxmox.com/proxmox-ve ), and you can manage it from any computer that has a web browser, with more management features than Hyper-V. I love it.

Comment: @LonnieBest `These days, instead of providing standalone installers [...] they have restricted and predefined "feature menus". If it's not on the menu, you can't add it.`  That's actually less true now than ever - most everything that can be installed from one of those menus can be installed via PowerShell, because those installers now use PowerShell on the back-end.  Many of their installers (like for Exchange) will provide you the complete listing of the Powershell commands and scripts performed, which is incredibly helpful in automation and large deployments.

Comment: @LonnieBest Not really. It's only Essentials that is feature-restricted. Standard and Datacenter have the full feature set, their only real difference is in virtualization rights. It's much simpler than with 2008/2008 R2.

Comment: Hyper-V is available on Server 2012 R2 Essentials, both the service and the management tools. 
So if you want to do Hyper-V on a cheap(ish) Windows Server, you can use 2012 R2 Essentials.

Comment: @HopelessN00b - just because you can now do everything in PowerShell and the GUI tools also show you PowerShell scripts for their current operation, it doesn't mean things are now all using PowerShell as their back-end. Dism, IIS, Exchange, AD - the PowerShell cmdlets are just wrappers around existing APIs, mostly COM based. I'm not complaining, it's great, but PowerShell hardly ever does the real work, it is just a nice layer on top of the existing APIs.

Comment: @LonnieBest it appears Microsoft [has heard your cries](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2013/09/03/understanding-licensing-for-windows-server-2012-r2-essentials-and-the-windows-server-essentials-experience-role.aspx).

Comment: @MDMoore313 : Addressing my cries is honorable and appreciated. Have you ever noticed how Microsoft URLs can't survive the ages? When I find information, at a Microsoft URL, that I know I'll need to reference later, I always save it to PDF in addition to bookmarking it, because (more than likely) that URL won't point to anything specific over time (as showcased in the [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2013/09/03/understanding-licensing-for-windows-server-2012-r2-essentials-and-the-windows-server-essentials-experience-role.aspx) you provided).

Answer (score 2):

I realize this post is a couple months old, but you should update your version of Essentials, Microsoft has bundled in Hyper-V with Essentials, both the service as well as the manager.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2013/09/03/understanding-licensing-for-windows-server-2012-r2-essentials-and-the-windows-server-essentials-experience-role.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Install a server. No Hyper-V = no admin tools.

Comment: Please elaborate a little. I'm not sure I know exactly what you mean by "server" in this context (given that I'm dealing with servers, virtual servers, and services); please cater to my perceived ambiguity a little.

Comment: I am completely certain that with a standard version of 2012 you do not have to have the Hyper-V role installed to have the Hyper-V management tools installed.  I am just not sure about essentials.

Comment: Yes, but essentials does not have the Hyper-V role AT ALL - including the management tools. No Hyper-V (not installed, NOT THERE).

Comment: Funny how  Iget downvotes and all the ignorant (as in: ignoring reality) answers are wrong in fact. Whow. Brave new world.

Comment: You are right that it is not there. Do you know of anyone ever installing this application from standalone executable?

Comment: Nope. I dare saying that the market for this particular specific Windows Server edition is quite tiny - most people liklely go with a full server.  I would just install RSAT (Remote Server Administration Tools) on a Workstation. It is not like this server can virtual machines, so nothing is lost.